How to make 0.100000000000001 caused by rounding effects become 0.1 again?
When doing "correct mathematics" floating point effects cause a number 0.1 to become 0.100000000000001.
So I want to do some "rounding", but I'm unsure how to do it:
When doing something like sprintf('%.3f', $val) there will be always three fractional digits like 0.100.
For the concrete example I could use format %.1f, but that 0.1 is just one example (it could be 0.125 as well).
What I want is "at most three fractional digits" (considered to be "enough" precision for my case).
Are there better solutions than print int($x * 1000) / 1000 while only using Perl core packages?
  DB<1> $x=0.100000000000001

  DB<2> print int($x * 1000) / 1000
0.1
  DB<3>


In what way should something be "better" than sprintf or int()? You mean easier to use, more correct? Surely using the number as-is is best for precision and math.

These aren't rounding effects; floating point can't represent every number exactly so it tries to be close enough. Just use sprintf like you showed, instead of additional floating point operations. The more you mess around with the number, the worse the potential error gets.

print doesn't show the whole number. See:
my $x = 0.100000000000001;
printf "%1.20f\n", int($x * 1000) / 1000;

Output:
0.10000000000000000555

Read What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.
To use arbitrary precission, use Math::BigFloat, which is a core module.
use Math::BigFloat;
my $x = 'Math::BigFloat'->new('0.1');
print $x * 1e30;
# Output: 100000000000000000000000000000


Fun fact: You need up to 1074 decimal places (%.1074f) or 751 in scientific notation (%.751g) to see the whole number with IEEE doubles.

You don't even need the int($x * 1000) / 1000 phrase.
my $x = 0.100000000000001; printf "%1.20f\n", $x; gets me 0.10000000000000000555

You suggest using  Math::BigFloat, but could you mention how to use Math::BigFloat to achieve the desired stringification?

It seems Math::BigFloat is bit of an overkill to solve the problem; what would be the specific advantage using it?

I thought that the main problem was getting 0.100000000000001 in the first place.

Operations that should produce 0.1 are currently producing 0.100000000000001 despite using "correct mathematics" (i.e. due to floating-point error). They want to round the incorrect result of 0.100000000000001 to get the desired result of 0.1. That much is clear. What isn't clear is whether they want to get the string 0.1 (which is supported by the fact that they said they don't want 0.100), or the number 0.1 (which is impossible, since 1/10 is periodic in binary).

(Note that they can't possibly be getting 0.100000000000001 either, since that can't be represented by a float-point number. That's already being rounded. They seem to be under the impression math operations introduce floating-point error, when it's simply storing a number that introduces the error.)

Since we're talking about the stringification of numbers, we first look at sprintf. It doesn't give us what we want, but it gets us close. So we'll use it, then remove the undesirable trailing zeroes.
sprintf( '%.3f', $val ) =~ s/\.?0+\z//r

